# Nose: find test generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose

I'm having a little issue with the nose testing framework.

**Scenario:**

I want to test my software with devices I have connected to my computer. Each device is tested with different set of configurations. Luckily, as the testing code does not change, I can simply create files containing the configurations for each device.

For now, I have used normal test methods inside my class. Meaning that inside of my test method I'm loading the configuration file for the device I want to test and then iterate over all configurations in that file and perform the test. Unfortunately, this only gives one test result per device, not one per configuration the devices was tested with.

So I stumbled over nose own test generators. The old tests were modified so they are using a generator and everything worked fine so far, I got a result for each configuration, everything worked great.

**My little Issue:**

However, I've seen to hit a wall now. When using --collect-only to show the available tests, I get one of two possible outcomes:

1. A configuration file is loaded and the test generator generates the tests according to that configuration file. This means that nose displays the test with each possible parameter configuration. However, as the configuration file may not be the right one for the device I want to test later on, I get false result.
2. I found out that the plug-in that offers the --collect-only functionality bypasses the fixtures of the tests. So I moved the loading of the configuration into a fixture to avoid having the generated tests spam the list of available tests. Unfortunately, this resulted in no test being generated and hence not test being displayed as the generator didn't generate anything

**What I tried so far:**

So, I have tried a few things to solve this issue:

1. Using a flag to determine if --collect-only is running. As the collect plug-in bypasses the fixtures, I have set a flag in the generator with a default value of true and set it to false in the fixture of that generator. I hoped that checking the flag and simply ignoring the test generation when --collect-only was running would solve my issue. That was when I learned that nose checks if a test method is a generator and expects it to give test method.
2. As my first idea failed because nose knows that the function is a generator and expects at least one generated function from it, my second idea was to call the function with an empty set of parameters. As my configuration is stored in a dict(), I simply passed an empty dict. Luckily, this was enough to generate a test. However, apparently, nose makes a little check if the test is executable and if it fails, the test is once again ignored.
3. After the second fail I tried the other direction. I read the source code of nose a bit, trying to figure out how it works internally. That was when I stumbled over the "isgenerator()" check. So I thought, I would scan my directories for the tests on my own, add all static tests I find to a list and when I stumble across a generator, I will not generate tests, but add the name of the generator to the lists of tests. Well, this one fails so far as I have no real experience on how nose works internally. Meaning, I find all the static tests, however not the generators. For the moment, this is my code to find the tests:

   k
       from nose.loader import TestLoader
       from nose.util import isgenerator
       import os

   ```
   folder = os.getcwd()
   testLoader = TestLoader()
   tests = testLoader.loadTestsFromDir(folder)
   for testModule in tests:
   print ("Found test module %s" % testModule.id())
   for testFile in testModule:
       print ("Found test file %s" % testFile.id())
       for test in testFile:
           print("Found test %s" % test.id())
           if not isgenerator(test):
               for x in test:
                   print("Found x %s" % x.id())
           else:
               print ("GENERATOR FOUND")
   ```

I ran out of ideas on what to try. Maybe I ran in some sort of X-Y problem, or maybe I'm simply blind to see the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, after jumping through the debugger a bit more, I came up with the following solution and will post it here as an answer because it seems to work. However, it is neither really elegant looking nor do I know how stable it is exactly.

```
foundTests = dict()
    for testPackage in loadedTests:
        #print ("Found test module %s" % testModule.id())
        for testModule in testPackage:
            #print ("Found test file %s" % testFile.id())
            for testCase in testModule:
                #print("Found test %s" % test.id())
                    for test in testCase:
                        if isinstance(test, Test):
                            key, value = readTestInformation(test)
                            foundTests[key] = value

                        elif hasattr(test, "test_generator"):
                            factory = test.factory
                            for suite in factory.suites:
                                try:
                                    if inspect.ismethod(suite):
                                        key, value = readGeneratedTestInformation(suite)
                                        foundTests[key]=value
                                except:
                                    pass
```

This function simply iterates over all packages found, inside them iterates over all modules found, inside the modules it iterates over all classes and at last iterates over all test methods inside a class.

If a test method is a generator it seems to have the "test_generator" attribute, so I check for that and then iterate over all suites inside the factory, checking each time if it is a function. If it is, I got the test generator function.

So, if anyone comes up with a better solution, I'd be happy to see it. This way seems kind of hacky.